# Roku SceneGraph - check URL for 404

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I'm new to Roku coding and I was wondering if there is a simple Function (non-Task Node) that I can use to check and see if a URL is valid or not and then just return a Yay or Nay so I can check a second URL? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find what you are looking for here: [roSystemLog](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roSystemLog)

You also have a good sample code in this link that you can follow.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response but that looks way over my head. I don't understand it :( Do I just call it like : showVideoScreenWithLogging(URL)? what will the return be?

Comment: Hey, U.Mitic Any Exception Handling Statement available in Roku? Like try-catch or any else?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running Eval() on the url call, and check for a 400-level error. If the error is present then proceed to another Eval() call on the next url you want, and so on until you get a URL you can break out of the function with. Eval() will test the code, and if no errors will proceed, but if it throws a runtime error it will just stop THAT code execution and not crash the application. It's a pretty decent ad-hoc exception handler. See here:  https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Runtime+Functions#RuntimeFunctions-Eval(codeasString)asDynamic

Comment: Hello, I tried to print : Print Eval("http://www.server.net/badfile.xml") 
But all it printed was <Component: roList> =
(
    <Component: roAssociativeArray>
)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a request to the URL with an `roTransfer`, and check for errors. In this example, I'm using a `GetHead()`, since all you need to do is check for validity.

```
' given a 404 URL
url = "http://example.com/404"

' request HEAD for the URL
urlTransfer = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
urlTransfer.setUrl(url)
urlEvent = urlTransfer.head()
if urlEvent <> Invalid
    responseCode = urlEvent.getResponseCode()
    if responseCode >= 200 and responseCode < 300
        print "success"
    else
        print "fail with code " + Stri(responseCode)
    end if
else
    print "transfer failed"
end if
```

Comment: Hello, I'll try this but I think I tried this already and I get a Debug error about roUrlTransfer cannot be used as a Task node due to the file it's being run in. I need to have the check done as a simple function. I'll let you know.